# Xamarin.Forms bindings - Is implicit type conversion being done in code, but not in XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, implicit-conversion

In a Xamarin.Forms project I'm working, I noticed we're binding a lot of integer values to label text. For example:

```
myLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, nameof(MyViewModel.TotalQty));
```

Where `MyViewModel.TotalQty` is an `int`.

[This article from the Xamarin guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/) says:

> In Xamarin.Forms, bindings do not perform any implicit type conversions, and if you need to display a non-string object as a string you must provide a type converter or use StringFormat.

But the code I'm using is working, so there's obviously implicit type conversion going on there. So my conclusion is that either the statement in the article is wrong/outdated, or the statement applies to XAML, but not code. I'm having trouble finding an answer on this online - does anyone know?

Comment: If the quoted text were true, it would be a marked departure from previous `Xaml` implementations.  Absent any explicit `ValueSerializer` or `TypeConverter` attribute for the source or target property, I would expect the `TypeConverter` for the source or target type to be used, and any built-in `TypeConverter` ought to be able to convert to `String`.  The default converter for `String` certainly can.  Regardless, there should be no difference between constructing a binding in C# vs Xaml, though there would likely be differences for any `Trigger`-like type, if Xamarin even has those.

Comment: (To be clear, I do not have an answer for you, but I will watch this question with interest.)

Answer (score 0):

Not talking about official documentation, but in my experience I've noticed the bind is set like an object extension (the values are simply used like `object` as you can see [here at the source code](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/BindableObject.cs)), and should have an explicit type conversions internaly from the value to the target type, once is needed set up the type of the property when creating a bindable property.

For example:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty MyCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(MyCommand), typeof(Command), typeof(MyObjectType), null, BindingMode.OneWay);
public Command MyCommand
{
    get { return (Command)GetValue(MyCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyCommandProperty, value); }
}
```

Some points to note:

- In the `Create` method of static BindableProperty, I set up the real type of my property (Command - 2nd arg);
- In my property, I use the `SetValue` method, that receives an `object` value;
- The typed MyCommand property forces the internal use of it to be of the same type, like `MyProperty = new Command(() => { return; });` and makes things like `MyProperty = string.Empty;` invalid;

Remembering that the XAML code is a markup language, and the whole code will be 'translated' to C#. Naturally can have some inferences and conventions on the use of it, but the same rules are applied.

I hope it helps you. (I'm sorry for my bad english)